# Recommend versioned backup solution for NAS at home

Tags: backup, nas, windows-home-server

I have a Windows Home Server which I would like to backup to a secondary NAS located on the local network.

Requirements for the backup are as follows:

1. Some kind of control over backing-up a subset of data that I've selected (e.g. top level shares is fine).
2. Incremental backups (only backups data that has changed).
3. Backup supports versioning i.e. will keep the last X versions of a file and/or all versions of a file not older than Y (where X and Y are configurable).
4. Backups are encrypted.
5. I do not want another PC to drive or mediate the backup.

If there is a NAS solution that can do this then I would happily replace my WHS for that NAS. E.g. I've looked at the QNAP NAS solutions which do support rsync and replication to another NAS but it does not support versioning of backups.

TIA

Comment: Have you considered ZFS, which has a snapshot feature? There is also encryption, and the ditto blocks feature can be used to demand extra redundancy. [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org/) version 8 should support all these features, except encryption.